# php and mysql - avoiding cache

Tags: php, mysql, cache-control

I have a problem that one of my users, make an insert into my mysql database, but when he goes to another page to list these inserts, it only return old data that was previous there. He can only see the changes after several minutes or even hours.

I read that If I add a random number in my url, I can avoid cache, but still not working.

I tried to put these headers on php.

```
header("Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

And I tried this one too:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE...
```

None work. Still don't get any visible changes.

Comment: Please provide if you use some kind of framework. eg. wordpress, drupal, cakePHP, yii, symfony, etc... or some templating engine, that can cache. eg. twig...

Comment: Have you tried to add the `Expires` header, setting it to 0?

Comment: No is just simple php.

Comment: @Michel yes I tried many options with header, none seems to work

Comment: This can be some problem in clients browser? The others users are just fine.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code that modifies the database and that retrieves the results.  The caching problem is *probably* on the client side.  MySQL is ACID compliant, meaning that once a transaction completes, then the modified data should be visible to all clients.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Expires headers in your htaccess file. You will need to ask your user to Ctrl+F5 (Force refresh) for it to correctly take effect;

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

This will tell the browser not to cache the text and html within that directory and any subdirectories (unless otherwise specified). I had a similiar issue and resolved it with this when I realised my caching was affecting the update of live data.

Comment: sorry, I don't have permission to access .htaccess in my web server.

Comment: If you have ftp access, you should be able to upload one into your root directory, most shared hosts still allow it, just not editting php.ini. If not, sorry I couldn't be of much assistance.